# How to find Twitter users who follow a certain set of other people?

Tags: twitter

All I can find is really old stuff and paid for marketing tools. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Never mind, I found what I was looking for. For those interested, it's called [Twiangulate](http://www.twiangulate.com/search), and I can't wait to try it out! 